# Restful método DELETE

Tags: rest, restful

Dentro da arquitetura Rest temos os verbos `POST`, `GET` `PUT` e `DELETE`.
Dentre os vários exemplos e tutoriais que eu estudei. O uso do verbo`DELETE` é sempre exemplificado com `DELETE /addresses/1`, onde basicamente passo o **endereço** e o **ID** do que quero deletar. Porém, em casos em que eu precise passar mais parâmetros na URL como `DELETE` `/addresses/id/codUsuario`. Isso também está correto dentro da estrutura **REST**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideia em si é válida.

Eu não vejo problemas desde que `id` e `codUsuario` formem algum tipo de chave composta para acessar este recurso no qual deseja remover OU ambos formem uma URL no qual o conjunto destas duas informações possam apontar para um único recurso, em uma relação pai e filho.

Vou dar um exemplo de cada caso. Primeiro, com chave composta.

### Primeiro exemplo

Se deseja remover um documento no qual a chave composta é tipo do documento e o seu número:

```
/documentos/{tipo-documento}/{numero}
```

A request ficaria:

```
DELETE /documentos/CPF/12312312300/
```

Agora vamos ao segundo exemplo.

### Segundo exemplo

Você pode ter os pedidos e produtos, e deseja acessar o produto dentro de um pedido (ou removê-lo, no seu caso).

```
/pedidos/{id-pedido}/produtos/{id-produto}
```

E a request:

```
DELETE /pedidos/123/produtos/3333
```

**Contudo**, olhando o exemplo que deu, seu endpoint está bem estranho, não parece ser nenhum dos dois casos pois não é possível ver uma relação natural entre `id` e `codUsuario`. Precisaríamos entender o contexto por trás deste endpoint para uma melhor solução. Talvez, você esteja procurando algo assim:

```
DELETE /users/{codUsuario}/addresses/{idAddress}
```

Comment: Sim, para mim também faz muito sentido usar desta forma. Só gostaria de ter certeza de estar seguindo o padrão REST. No meu caso eu tenho uma chave composta N para N. Onde não faria sentido eu usar um id para esta tabela. Pelo menos, por padrão não se usa. Um exemplo de umas dessas tabelas que tenho é a post_curtido, onde os identificadores são usuario_id e post_id. Sendo assim, para descurtir um post precisaria usar um comando DELETE /url+rota/usuario_id/post_id

Comment: @alan, se sua intenção é curtir/descurtir um post, creio que vai se interessar em ver como o Github [controla star/unstar](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#unstar-a-repository) na API deles.

Answer (score 3):

**Resposta curta:** sim.

---

O [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) que especifica o método `DELETE` descreve-o da seguinte forma:

> "Na verdade, esse método é semelhante ao comando rm no UNIX: ele expressa uma operação de exclusão no mapeamento de URI do servidor de origem, em vez de uma expectativa de que as informações associadas anteriormente sejam excluídas."
> ([traduzido via Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/pt/In%20effect%2C%20this%20method%20is%20similar%20to%20the%20rm%20command%20in%20UNIX%3A%20it%20expresses%20a%20deletion%20operation%20on%20the%20URI%20mapping%20of%20the%20origin%20server%20rather%20than%20an%20expectation%20that%20the%20previously%20associated%20information%20be%20deleted.))

Como tal é perfeitamente viável apagar recursos que estão associados a outros recursos da mesma forma que é possível fazer `rm` de ficheiros/diretórios que estão dentro de outros diretórios.

Deve ser tido sempre em consideração que caso seja apagado o recurso *pai* pode não fazer sentido os restantes recursos existirem. Pegando no exemplo da pergunta, faz sentido apagar uma morada sem apagar um utilizador mas não faz sentido apagar um utilizador sem apagar as suas moradas.

No [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE) consta que um pedido `DELETE` *pode* conter um body porém essa prática vai contra ao originalmente descrito no [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) e não é garantido que seja suportado por todas as implementações do método `DELETE`.